# Rotation of list, Python using modulo function

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, rotation, modulo

I am a beginner in Python. I am trying to solve the following problem using *modulo* *function* but I'm facing

```
error: list index out of range.
```

**Problem:** Given an array of integers `arr[]` of size N and an integer, the task is to rotate the array elements to the left by `d` positions.

**Code:**

```py
def rotate(arr, d):
    temp= []
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        temp[i]=temp[(i+d)%n]
        return temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this part of code `temp[(i+d)%n]`, you are trying to access an element of a list that is empty. Because of this, your program produces that error. You probably meant to write `arr[(i+d)%n]` instead.

Also, when you write `temp[i]`, Python expects your list to be longer than `i`.
Instead of this, you can use `temp.append(element)` to add an element at end of the list.

After these changes, your function should look like this.

```py
def rotate(arr, d):
    temp = []
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        temp.append(arr[(i+d)%n])
    return temp
```